# Exchange mailbox "AllItems" folder - likelihood of presence in Exchange mailboxes in the year 2020

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, mapi

I'm trying to confirm if the "AllItems" hidden folder is safe to assume that it will be present in all mailboxes which reside in Exchange 2010 and newer.  I've seen a few articles, particularly the ones by Glen Scales, where it is mentioned that the folder is created by Outlook 2010 when the mailbox is on Exchange 2010.  In all my testing, it seems like every mailbox on Exchange 2010 and newer has this folder, but in all those tests, Outlook 2010 is nowhere in site, so I assume it is a default folder in all new mailboxes in Exchange 2010 and newer.

Does anyone know for certain if my assumption is correct?  I'd like to use this folder in some scripts that I have plans to write.  So I'm also trying to figure out strategy for if the folder isn't found.  I could just create it if it's not found, however, I'd like to know the out of the box nature of it first, just to be safe and out of curiosity.

Comment: As far as I know it is always there. But if it doesn't exist, you can always create it - it is just a  regular search folder.

Comment: From Exchange 2016 on it should always be there because the Outlook Rest API and now the Graph use it for their Messages endpoint.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Both points are perfect to hear.  Wasn't sure if it had something special about it, which would make me creating it less ideal than having the original, and glad to hear the future-friendliness of it, as I'm learning both MS Graph and EWS Managed API.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the concrete answer about AllItems.  When you try to delete it (I've only tested with Exchange 2019 in my lab), you get:

"Distinguished folders cannot be deleted."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/handling-deletion-related-errors-in-ews-in-exchange - this page's explanation of the error tells me it's a Default folder:

> Indicating that default folders cannot be deleted.